# Looking for a config file in fedora (33) where the basic terminal parameters for a CLI login are stored

Tags: command-line, fedora, virtualbox

I am running a Fedora 33 server instance in Virtualbox with login at the command line.
(No xserver)

Within the virtualbox CLI display for this server, I want to find out if there is any way to expand the screen format with more lines and more width with the same font size (or smaller font).

Is there a CLI config file in fedora where this can be done ?

Comment: Do you use fbcon?